# How to check indexer reindex progress in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, product, reindex, indexing

I have 60 million products in my Magento 2 Store and i have run `php bin/magento indexer:reindex` query using terminal.

Now the issue is that the indexer running from around 100 hours but it will show processing on **catalog_category_product** in ID.

Is there any way to check the progress of `indexer:reindex`.
I have check show processlist and it shows
[image]

I have checked in db and there is no table regarding catalog_category_product_index_store1_tmp this name and the two table with catalog_category_product_index_store1 and catalog_category_product_index_store1_replica exist.

**So my problem is how do i check the progress of indexer:reindex in Magento 2.**

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run this command `bin/magento indexer:status`, it will show the list of all the indexer along with its status.

Comment: Thanks for the response it will show processing on one status and it will running from a long time.

Comment: Reset the indexer using bin/magento indexer:reset and then just reindex only the required one.

Comment: I have done that actually my product is 60 million so how much time it will take any idea about this ?

Comment: Check your memory limit. Due to that, it may be the issue