# How do I check the progress of a reindex with status 'processing'?

Tags: database, magento2.4, reindex, indexing

I am running the following command
`php -d memory_limit=-1 bin/magento indexer:reindex foo`

When running it on my table, my terminal goes haywire showing the following:

```
Memory used: 706M
Memory used: 706M
Memory used: 706M
Memory used: 706M
Memory used: 706M
Memory used: 706M
Memory used: 706M
Memory used: 706M
Memory used: 706M
Memory used: 706M
Memory used: 706M
Memory used: 706M
Memory used: 706M
Memory used: 706M
```

And so on. It's also dumping this in real time into the terminal, so I can't type anything. The only way out is `Ctrl+C`

When I check `bin/magento indexer:status` it shows `foo` as `processing`.

I've already checked this [How to check indexer reindex progress in Magento 2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/328531/how-to-check-indexer-reindex-progress-in-magento-2) and it is NOT an answer to my solution, because I've reset the index and started over several times, as well as set the memory limit to -1, which should be infinite, and my machine has lots of memory, 32 GB, and the whole DB is only 6GB.

Is there a way to see how far along it is when it's status is `processsing`? Or am I actually killing the processes when I do `Ctrl+C` in the terminal, I'm guessing so but not quite sure.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to see how far along it is when it's status is processsing? Or am I actually killing the processes when I do Ctrl+C in the terminal, I'm guessing so but not quite sure.

Yes, Ctrl+C will kill the process. Try the below method If you want to run the command in the background.

```
/var/www/html# php bin/magento indexer:reindex > /dev/null 2>&1 &
[1] 137  - It is a process ID, you can use it later if you want to kill this specific process id.
/var/www/html# jobs -l
[1]+   137 Running                 php bin/magento indexer:reindex > /dev/null 2>&1 &
/var/www/html# jobs -l
[1]+   137 Exit 1                  php bin/magento indexer:reindex > /dev/null 2>&1
/var/www/html# jobs -l
/var/www/html#
```